# Do all GPUs use the same architecture?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

I have some experience with nVIDIA CUDA and am now thinking about learning openCL too. I would like to be able to run my programs on any GPU. My question is: does every GPU use the same architecture as nVIDIA (multi-processors, SIMT stracture, global memory, local memory, registers, cashes, ...)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with your stated goal:

"I would like to be able to run my programs on any GPU."

Then yes, you should learn OpenCL.

In answer to your overall question, other GPU vendors do use different architectures than Nvidia GPUs.  In fact, GPU designs from a single vendor can vary by quite a bit, depending on the model.

This is one reason that a given OpenCL code may perform quite differently (depending on your performance metric) from one GPU to the next.  In fact, to achieve optimized performance on any GPU, an algorithm should be "profiled" by varying, for example, local memory size, to find the best algorithm settings for a given hardware design.

But even with these hardware differences, the goal of OpenCL is to provide a level of core functionality that is supported by all devices (CPUs, GPUs, FPGAs, etc) and include "extensions" which allow vendors to expose unique hardware features. Although OpenCL cannot hide significant differences in hardware, it does guarantee portability. This makes it much easier for a developer to start with an OpenCL program tuned for one device and then develop a program optimized for another architecture.

To complicate matters with identifying hardware differences, the terminology used by CUDA is different than that used by OpenCL, for example, the following are roughly equivalent in meaning:

```
CUDA:           OpenCL:
```

```
Thread         Work-item
Thread block    Work-group
Global memory   Global memory
Constant memory Constant memory
Shared memory   Local memory
Local memory    Private memory
```

More comparisons and discussion can be [found here](http://developer.amd.com/resources/heterogeneous-computing/opencl-zone/programming-in-opencl/porting-cuda-applications-to-opencl/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be safe to say that every GPU uses the SIMT architecture?

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not an expert on this aspect. Single Instruction Multiple Threads (SIMT) is a term created by Nvidia to describe their GPU architectures. These architectures are basically Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) with multithreading.  Although the term SIMT was created by Nvidia, other vendors have come up with similar architectures, but I don't necessarily think these are exactly the same thing.

Comment: I think you're giving him problematic advice, in that while writing his code in OpenCL would allow it to run on different GPUs (well, ignoring OpenCL version issues, which can't be ignored) - almost no kernel runs _well_ on many GPUs. The architecture's differences have, as we all know, a huge impact on the approach to maximizing performance.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that the kinds of abstraction provided by OpenCL and CUDA are very similar.  You can also usually count on your hardware having similar features: global mem, local mem, streaming multiprocessors, etc...

Switching from CUDA to OpenCL, you may be confused by the fact that many of the same concepts have different names (for example: CUDA "warp" == OpenCL "wavefront").